# Groovy Method isSynthetic is false for run and main

Tags: java, groovy

I'm parsing a groovy script via Java using reflection to get the methods from the script.
For my project I need all the methods that are non-synthetic and public.

```
GroovyScriptEngine groovyScriptEngine = new GroovyScriptEngine(scriptFile.getAbsolutePath());
Class<GroovyObject> scriptClass = groovyScriptEngine.loadScriptByName(scriptFile.getName());

// some code

GroovyObject groovyObject = scriptClass.getConstructor().newInstance();
if (groovyObject != null) {
    Method[] declaredMethods = groovyObject.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
    return Arrays.stream(declaredMethods)
          .filter(m -> !m.isSynthetic() && Modifier.isPublic(m.getModifiers()))
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

For a normal groovy class this returns all the getters and setter and public user-defined methods.

For example:

```
class MyGroovyClass {
     def int number = 1

     int add(int anotherNumber) {
          return number + anotherNumber
     }
}
```

Parsing the groovy class returns getNumber, setNumber, addNumber.
For an empty groovy class (no fields, no declared methods) this returns an empty list.

But for an **empty script** (= completely empty file) this returns the methods "run" and "main".

Why does getting and filtering (for non-synthetic and public) methods from an empty groovy script return "run" and "main"?
How can I filter for those two methods? (Or can I catch that case earlier?)

Answer (score 1):

Well, groovy script has to be compiled into something that runs on JVM and has an entry point, apparently it only be a class with `main` method.

So basically groovy script gets compiled into a class, the body of the script is copied into `run` method, and `main` method has to be specified as an entry point as I've explained. At some point main will call run (indirectly).

Hence for each script you'll get these methods.

Its describe in [groovy documentation](https://groovy-lang.org/structure.html) (see paragraph `3.2. Script class`)

Comment: It's just interesting that the GroovyScriptEngine (or whatever) makes up a completely fictitious class and inserts main and run methods. Instead of just concluding "empty file => no script => no code. Good Bye!"

Comment: Well, it might be subjective, but an empty script still can be run, just like if you create a java class with an empty main method, it still can be run.... But I'm not affiliated with groovy so I can't really give you a qualified answer on this :)

Comment: hm, yeah, but your java example makes sense, because at least there is a class. but in my question the file is completely empty. no code at all. which made me think this wouldn't compile at all or lead to null/NPE. but that groovy just makes up a class is weird. thanks for your comments.